# Безопасность Github Releases в Travis CI

Tags: github, непрерывная-интеграция, travis

Здравствуйте. В документации Travis CI указано, что для загрузки артефактов на Github Releases, я должен записать oauth token в .travis.yml.

Если проект открытый и .travis.yml лежит в корне репозитория, безопасно ли так делать, ведь каждый может увидеть токен?

Если нет, то как решить эту проблему в открытом репозитории?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы создадите ключ с помощью команды `travis setup releases`, то Travis автоматически зашифрует его и в файле `.travis.yml` будет токен, которым можно будет пользоваться только после расшифровывания (скорее всего, это даже случайный хэш). Ваш настоящий токен будет храниться на серверах Travis CI.

Цитата из [документации](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases):

> it is highly recommended to use travis setup releases, which will automatically create a GitHub oauth token with the correct scopes and encrypts it.

Кроме того, вы можете сохранять токен в переменных окружения, настраивая их на вкладке "Settings" в проекте. Об этом так же написано в [документации](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables).